# Index was out of range wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a function that gets the running apps every 10 seconds, place them on a listbox and sends them to the other window if you click the send button. Now the problem is whenever I try to open then immediately close an app, it would send an error pointing to my list.
I'm not sure what to do here.

```
 Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index.
```

Here's my code if in case it brings any help:

```
private List<int> listedProcesses = new List<int>();
    private void SendData()
    {
        String processID = "";
        String processName = "";
        String processFileName = "";
        String processPath = "";
        string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

        listBox1.BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                piis = GetAllProcessInfos();
                try
                {
                    if (!listedProcesses.Contains(piis[i].Id)) //place this on a list to avoid redundancy
                    {
                        listedProcesses.Add(piis[i].Id);
                        processID = piis[i].Id.ToString();
                        processName = piis[i].Name.ToString();
                        processFileName = piis[i].FileName.ToString();
                        processPath = piis[i].Path.ToString();
                        output.Text += "\n\nSENT DATA : \n\t" + processID + "\n\t" + processName + "\n\t" + processFileName + "\n\t" + processPath + "\n";
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   wait.Abort();
                   output.Text += "Error..... " + ex.StackTrace;
                }

                NetworkStream ns = tcpclnt.GetStream();
                String data = "";
                data = "--++" + "  " + processID + " " + processPath + " " + processFileName + " " + hostName;

                if (ns.CanWrite)
                {
                    byte[] bf = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(data);
                    ns.Write(bf, 0, bf.Length);
                    ns.Flush();
                } 
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            listBox1.EndUpdate();
        } 
    }

 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessInfoItem pii = piis.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == (int)(sender as ListBox).SelectedValue); //setting value for list box
        if (pii != null)
        {
            string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

            textBox4.Text = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = (pii.FileName);
            textBox6.Text = (pii.Path);
            textBox7.Text = hostName;
        }
    }

    private List<ProcessInfoItem> piis = new List<ProcessInfoItem>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        piis = GetAllProcessInfos();
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
        listBox1.DataSource = piis;
        textBox1.Text = GetIpAdd().ToString();
    }
    private List<ProcessInfoItem> GetAllProcessInfos()
    {

        List<ProcessInfoItem> result = new List<ProcessInfoItem>();
        Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                ProcessInfoItem pii = new ProcessInfoItem(p.Id,p.MainModule.ModuleName, p.MainWindowTitle, p.MainModule.FileName);
                result.Add(pii);
            }
        }
        return result;
    } 
    public class ProcessInfoItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public ProcessInfoItem(int id, string name, string filename, string path)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.FileName = filename;
            this.Path = path;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it should be "listBox1.Items.Count - 1" in your for loop

Comment: @KarthikGanesan OP is using `<` so `Count` is OK.

Comment: Why do you think that the `piis` upper bound not bigger than `listBox1.Items.Count`

Comment: Sounds like `GetAllProcessInfos` is returning a different number of items than `listBox1.Items.Count`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response sir. I know this might sound dumb but can you point out to me on why?

Comment: @helpmeplease I don't know - you didn't post the method `GetAllProcessInfos` to kniw what it;s relationship to `listBox1` is.

Comment: Is your listbox ownerdrawn?

Comment: Your mistake that you didn't take in account the fact that the running processes can be changed since your last `listBox1` population.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indexing over a different collection that your `for` loop is referencing.  It sounds like you may want:

```
piis = GetAllProcessInfos();
for (int i = 0; i < piis.Count; i++)
{
```

instead.  However you are calling that function form *within* the `for` loop so it's not clear what you should be iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            piis = GetAllProcessInfos();
```

to

```
 piis = GetAllProcessInfos();
 for (int i = 0; i < piis.Count; i++)
        {
```